Division by neural network: Cannot take the length of shape with unknown rank
I am trying to code a neural network to multiply and divide two numbers by using a method similar to the one outlined here. First, I coded models for adding and subtracting two numbers, and squaring a number. For division, I then used the reciprocal of the divisor and multiplied it with the divident as below:
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers

#Models for adding and subtracting two numbers

num_train = 1000

X_train = np.random.rand(num_train, 2)
y_train_add = X_train[:, 0] + X_train[:, 1]
y_train_subtract = X_train[:, 0] - X_train[:, 1]

model_add = Sequential(
        [
            Dense(10),
            Dense(1)
            ]
        )

model_subtract = Sequential(
        [
            Dense(10),
            Dense(1)
            ]
        )

batch_size = 32
epochs = 100

model_add.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer='adam')
model_add.fit(X_train, y_train_add, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose = 1)


model_subtract.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer='adam')
model_subtract.fit(X_train, y_train_subtract, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose = 1)

#Model for squaring a number

x_train = np.random.random((10000,1))*100-50
y_train = np.square(x_train)

model_sqr = Sequential(
        [
            Dense(8, activation = 'relu', kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.001), input_shape = (1,)),
            Dense(8, activation = 'relu',  kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.001)),
            Dense(1)
            ]

        )

batch_size = 64
epochs = 2000

model_sqr.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer='adam')
model_sqr.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose = 1)

#Code for calculating the product and quotient of two numbers using models

x = "n" 
while True:
    print("enter first num:")
    x = input()
    if x == "end":
        break

    print("Enter operation:")
    op= input()

    print("enter second num:")
    y = input()

    X = int(x)
    Y = int(y)
    Ydiv = 1/Y

    if op == "*":
        predicted_product = model_sqr.predict(model_add.predict(np.array([[X, Y]]))) - model_sqr.predict(np.array([X])) -  model_sqr.predict(np.array([Y]))
        print(predicted_product/2)
    elif op =="/":
        predicted_quot = model_sqr.predict(model_add.predict(np.array([[X, Ydiv]]))) - model_sqr.predict(np.array([X])) -  model_sqr.predict(np.array([Ydiv]))
        print(predicted_quot/2)



The  multiplication part works reasonably well, but on inputting two numbers to be divided, the following error occurs:
Exception encountered when calling Sequential.call().

Cannot take the length of shape with unknown rank.

Can someone help me fix this?
EDIT: I changed Ydiv=1/Y TO Ydiv = np.reciprocal(Y), and although no error now shows up, every division I conduct yields a result of approximately some specific number (different values each time I run the program).
So now I'd like to know
1: How to fix this, and
2: How the error arose in the first place.

The problem with your approach is coming from the model performing square, which is very difficult to learn with your model. If you individually check it, you will see that it gives very wrong results for some values. Try seeing square(0), square(1), etc.

Note that the learned model has several "flat" areas which don't really match with the true curve. If you plot the squared error, it will show:

So the error is quite significant. As to always getting the same result, it is likely your model converged poorly, something like:

In this case, for the values in the -10, 10 region, you are likely getting a fixed output. So your formula (a + b)^2 - a^2 - b^2 is equivalent to c^2 - c^2 -c^2 = -c^2, where c is that constant. You are getting a different c each time as you are not using any np.random.seed.
To learn a better model of square, I have two suggestions:

Increase your number of samples, rather than epochs. Instead of 2000 epochs on 10K data, 200 epochs on 100K data may be more useful.
Change the activation from "relu" to something that also accomodates negative values, like "elu".

You will still not get a perfect square model, but it will be a much better approximation.
